# CSS3 move then animate

Tags: css, css-transitions

I am trying to animate my pages using css3 transitions.
I need to be able to move an element and then animate using css3.
For instance move  a hidden div off the screen and then animate it back on the screen.
Sounds strange I know but I have simplified my explanation and really do need this functionality. So in the code below I want to move the element 400px left and then animate it to 0. So....no animation move 400px, add CSS3 transition class and animate to 0px. Hope I have explained it ok...thanks for any help.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>My test page</title>
<style type="text/css">
    .box{
        height:100px;
        width:100px;
        background-color:green;
        position:absolute;
        top:100px;
    }
    .animator{
        -webkit-transition: all 1.5s ease;
        -moz-transition: all 1.5s ease;
        transition: all 1.5s ease;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.box').css({left:'400px'});
        $('.box').addClass('animator');
        $('.box').css({left:'0px'});

    });

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="box">1</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: +1 for the future of the web! CSS3 ftw :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a great explanation of how to use CSS3 animations on this page

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/CSS_animations

what I think you might be looking for is "keyframes" and it explains them on that page, it seems what you are looking for anyway, perhaps you can clarify your question a bit more?

Comment: Hi Christopher, I will have a good look at that page. If you go to my website http://www.freelancerlondon.com you will see that I have used jquery animations to bring in the pages to the user. I am trying to convert these animations to CSS3 animations (if available). So what I need to be able to do is move pages(divs) to the right of the screen and then animate them in to the viewable area.

Comment: I have a solution to the above problem.

    function animateMe(){
   $('.box').addClass('animator');
   $('.box').css({left:'0px'});
  } 
  
        $(document).ready(function(){
         $('.box').css({left:'400px'});
   setTimeout("animateMe()",1);
  });

by using the timeout, even though it is very small, it gives screen time to update. So the css3 animate class is only added after the element has moved.

Thanks for the answers

Paul

Comment: sounds to me like the page had exactly what you needed, keyframes.  here is a link to a specific example https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/cssref/animations/cssanim4.html


you want a "multi-stage-keyframed" animation of your page, then it's exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks Christopher, I have solved my problem and will post the solution in x hours (I have to wait to answer my own question..low rep) That page is awesome and is added to my favs for future study.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do

```
$('.box').animate({left:'400px'}).fadeIn().addClass('animator').animate({left:'0px'});
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't work. Well it does....but not how I need it to work....I need to move the div instantly to position and then animate it in. If you try and do the above you will see that the fadein causes a delay. If you specify a duration of 0 then the animate class is added too soon i.e before the screen updates with the new div position...causing it to slide to the new position and not move there instantly.....hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Animation is performed at the end of the application stack. So if you wrote:

```
// initial state -> elment has left 0
$('.box').css({left:'400px'}); // set left to 400
$('.box').addClass('animator');// set animation duration to 1.5s
$('.box').css({left:'0px'});   // set left to 0
// perform animation from 0 to 0
```

If you want to break the stack and perform browser operations, you can use window.setTimeout:

```
$('.box').css({left:'400px'}); // set left to 400
// move element from 0 to 400
window.setTimeout(function(){  
     $('.box').addClass('animator');// set animation duration to 1.5s
     $('.box').css({left:'0px'});   // set left to 0
},1)
// perform animation from 400 to 0
```

Comment: HI Tal, Thats the same code I used to illustrate that it doesn't work? The timeout method does work but you need to add at least 1 millisecond. I abandoned the use of CSS3 animations because of the lack of control. I needed to know when the animation finished. Unfortunately the finish event does not fire in certain browsers and I had to have a poll to check that the animation had indeed finished. So it was overly complicated.

Comment: I didn't noticed your solution, so I will not delete my answer. I will left it here for "quick readers".

Answer (score 0):

A simple Javascript timeout for a few milliseconds will allow the browser to reposition the element, and then apply a transformation afterwards.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.box').css({left:'400px'})
       .addClass('animator');
    setTimeout(function(){
       $('.box').css({left:'0px'});
    },15);

});
```